# Size limit of MySQL database table?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, python

I'm running a remote script that collects data from the web nightly.  Each morning I import the latest data to my database on my Mac using a command line import to phpMyAdmin, adding to the number of rows from the night before. I then access the data locally using a Python script.  Is there a limit to the size of a table that I can have either in terms of being able to store the data or access it via a query in Python?  And, if so, is there a way to check and see how close I am to the limit?

Please note that I'm not concerned with the import size since I'm just importing daily snapshots and inserting those newest rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has huge limits -- many terabytes.

You may run out of disk space.

Your app code may run out of RAM.  But only if you foolishly fetch all the rows at once.  Instead, use SQL to filter/summarize the data you fetch.

But otherwise, don't worry.

Comment: My mom always *did* tell me that I worried to much. :)